# Hibernate Criteria collection property (subquery?)

Tags: hibernate, subquery, criteria

I am not very familiar with Hibernate Criteria, and apologize if this question is too simple... However, any help is greatly appreciated!

I have two entities, CD and Track. Each CD has collection of Track-objects. In each Track there is a String-field named "title". Now I want to retrieve, using Hibernate Criteria all CDs having a Track with "title" set to a certain value. What I have so far is this:

```
//session handling
Criteria cdCriteria = session.createCriteria(CD.class);
DetachedCriteria trackCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Track.class);
trackCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("title", "SomeTitle"));
trackCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("title"));
criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(trackCriteria));
List<CD> cds = criteria.list();
```

This returns all CDs, regardless of track title. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're very close to the solution. You just missed the restriction stating than the track must be a track of the CD:

```
Criteria cdCriteria = session.createCriteria(CD.class, "cd");
DetachedCriteria trackCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Track.class, "track");
trackCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("track.title", "SomeTitle"));
trackCriteria.add(Restrictions.propertyEq("track.cd.id", "cd.id"));
trackCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("track.title"));
criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(trackCriteria));
List<CD> cds = criteria.list();
```

or

```
Criteria cdCriteria = session.createCriteria(CD.class, "cd");
DetachedCriteria trackCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Track.class, "track");
trackCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("track.title", "SomeTitle"));
trackCriteria.createAlias("track.cd", "trackCd");
trackCriteria.add(Restrictions.propertyEq("trackCd.id", "cd.id"));
trackCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("track.title"));
criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(trackCriteria));
List<CD> cds = criteria.list();
```

You could also avoid the subquery and simply use a join

```
Criteria cdCriteria = session.createCriteria(CD.class, "cd");
criteria.createAlias("cd.tracks", "track");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("track.title", "someTitle"));
criteria.setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get your last solution working, with the join. The two others fail with a mapping exception, Unknown entity: null I believe that is because of "track.cd", since "cd" is not a field in Track. The relation is directional from CD to Track only. Or am I tinking wrong here?

Comment: No, you're right. I assumed the association was bidirectional and a track had a cd field.

Comment: So, it is impossible to solve by using a subquery? Since the assocation is not bidirectional, the only way is by using joins?

Comment: Given that you need to access the tracks of the CD, I don't see how you could avoid a join between CD and Track.

Comment: There is a missing double quote in this line of the above answer, but StackOverflow does not allow me to fix it (minimum edit length must be 6 characters, apparently):  

criteria.createAlias("cd.tracks", track");

Answer (score 0):

You can do this actually without the join - simply use cdCriteria.getAlias() place of the string value of the alias. Thus, the key line would be:

```
trackCriteria.add(Restrictions.propertyEq("trackCd.id", cdCriteria.getAlias() + ".id"));
```

Comment: This uses the hibernate internal alias, rather than a user defined one.